# When switching to Jenkins mid-project, how to build artifacts for old tags?

Tags: c, svn, jenkins

I'm working on a project that has already been going on for a while. Unless I am mistaken, part of the use of Jenkins is to store artifacts for desired builds (i.e., releases or tags). This is preferable to me because I don't want to store binaries in the VCS system (SVN).

Moving forward, I can tag successful builds through Jenkins, and the artifacts will be stored forever. But what about old tags? Is there any way I can build all of the previous SVN tags so that the artifacts are available to anyone who needs?

I guess I could make a separate build for each tag, but that would be very tedious and make it difficult to find the artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parameters to the jenkins task, and have the parameter dropdowns populate from the SCM tags.  You can then use the parameter variables in the URL for the scm pulls.

So, when you go to run a build task, you can select the tag, and the appropriate source will be pulled.

If this is inline with what you're envisioning.  I'd be glad to expand.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [parameterized build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) task, which will check out by tag to build.  thus, you need only input the tag name at each build.

But I think you are mistaken -- Jenkins does store artifacts, but it does so more as a side effect of the build, and generally keeps only a couple of the last builds for disk space management.  If you want to maintain a library of previous builds, you probably want something like [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/).